# Как сделать проверку, что xls-файл пустой?

Tags: javascript, парсер, файлы, library

Использую библиотеку https://www.npmjs.com/package/xls-parser для парса данных xls-файла, но если попробовать загрузить пустой файл, то будет ошибка даже в самом примере библиотеки. Как проверить, что файл пустой?

Comment: Там промис. Обрабатывайте .catch

Comment: @AzizUmarov catch почему-то не видит нужную ошибку

Comment: А что он видит можно добавить код и ошибку?

Comment: @AzizUmarov если я собственноручно добавляю ошибку внутри промиса, то catch её ловит, а ошибка, которая возникает из-за пустого файла не ловится

Comment: @AzizUmarov у меня внутри промиса используется addEventListener и внутри него уже всякие действия, из-за которых возникает ошибка. Может поэтому он не может словить её, ведь второй параметр addEventListener асинхронный колбэк

Comment: Покажите код хоть частично укажите места в которых вы чегото ожидаете. Нам вот как понять что у вас в кодене так?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122707/discussion-between-anna-and-aziz-umarov).

Comment: Возможно надо не так это сделать
try { let res = onLoadEvent(binary, reader, hideEmptyRows, showNullProperties); resolve(res); } catch (e) {reject (e)}